# foswiki perl configuration shown as plain text in browser

Tags: apache, perl, foswiki

I am trying to install FosWiki on localhost. When I ran the configuration file (`localhost/wiki/bin/configure`), it's shown as plain text in browser. I'm sure `perl` is installed at `/usr/bin/perl`.

I also tried to allow Apache running scripts, here it my apache configuration file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/wiki/bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
            SetHandler cgi-script
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly did you do when you 'ran the configuration file'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: your need to install `libapache2-mod-perl` package in order to let Apache execute perl script.